# Firebase Database observeSingleEvent not working

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple function in my code which gets the users name. However, when it comes to the line saying observeSingleEvent, it skips the whole closure and exits the function. Any ideas why?

```
func getUsersName() {
    
    let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    
    // It comes to the line below
    ref?.child("users").child(userId!).child("name").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        
        // It skips all of that
        guard let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary else {
            return
        }
        
        let name = value["name"] as? String ?? ""
        
        print("Users name is: \(name)")
        
    })
    
} // And comes here
```

I have it just like in the docs from firebase. The idea is that I have a pair: name: "users_name" and I want to get the users name and display it in a table view.

Comment: If you're stepping through the code line by line, it is normal for it to skip over the completion handler as that is called asynchronously. If you put a breakpoint on `guard let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary else {`, does it reach that?

Comment: No it does not. It just skips the whole thing.

Comment: That sounds like either your device doesn't have a connection to the database servers, or that the user doesn't have read permission to the data. To figure out the latter, use the `withCancel:` overload of the method and check the `Error` value: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseQuery#observesingleeventof:with:withcancel: